# Good Practices for SQLite Model classes?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

In examples for SQLiteOpenHelper (and Room), a Java "model" class (e.g., Customer.java) is defined to represent 1 table from the database. For straightforward queries, such as "SELECT * From Customer", I can see how creating a Customer.java class is useful. However, what about a query combines data from multiple tables (e.g., Order & Customer) or an aggregate query that returns records summarizing data ... the "model" class quickly begins to degrade when your queries join information from multiple tables together and the results record structure is a mashup of fields from multiple tables.

Is there a standard or good practice for model class structure/naming that reflects the return table's structure cleanly in our Java code (example: SelectAllCustomerOrders( ) method with a SelectAllCustomerOrdersRecord class?). Any insight what others have done is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard or good practice for model class structure/naming that reflects the return table's structure cleanly in our Java code

For your example, you would have a Customer class and an Order Class the order would be related to a Customer. So you could not have a CustomerOrders class, or perhaps alternatively CustomerWithOrders. These would be POJO's rather than Entities (the tables)

The mashup is overcome by taking advantage of @Embedded annotations in conjunction with @Relation annotations.

Here's an example using Customer and Order :-

The Entities **Customer** and **Order**

```
@Entity
class Customer {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long customerId;
    String customerName;
    String customerUnitNumber;
    String customerAddress;
    String customerPostalCode;
    // etc

    Customer() {}
    @Ignore
    Customer(String customerName, String customerUnitNumber, String customerAddress, String customerPostalCode) {
        this.customerId = null;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.customerUnitNumber = customerUnitNumber;
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
        this.customerPostalCode = customerPostalCode;
    }

    ....
}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Order {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long orderId;
    Long customerReference;
    Integer quantity;
    // etc

    Order(){}
    @Ignore
    Order(long customerReference, int quantity) {
        this.orderId = null;
        this.customerReference = customerReference;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    ....
}
```

With the above then CustomerOrders could be :-

```
class CustomerOrders {
    @Embedded
    Customer customer;
    @Relation(entity = Order.class, parentColumn = "customerId", entityColumn = "customerReference")
    List<Order> orderList;
}
```

You could then have :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    long insertCustomer(Customer customer);
    @Insert
    long[] insertManyCustomers(Customer...customers);
    @Insert
    long insertOrder(Order order);
    @Insert
    long[] insertManyOrders(Order...orders);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer")
    List<Customer> getAllCustomers();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerId = :customerId")
    Customer getCustomerById(long customerId);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `order`")
    List<Order> getAllOrders();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE orderId = :orderId")
    Order getOrderById(long orderId);

    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM customer")
    long getCustomerCount();
    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM `order`")
    long getOrderCount();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer")
    List<CustomerOrders> getAllCustomersWithTheirOrders();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerId = :customerId")
    CustomerOrders getCustomerWithAllOrders(long customerId);

}
```

and the @Database e.g.

```
@Database(entities = {Customer.class,Order.class},version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();
}
```

Then consider the following (runs on main thread for brevity and convenience) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "DBINFO";
    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,TheDatabase.class,"thedatabase.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        // Add some data
        long[] customersAdded = dao.insertManyCustomers(
                new Customer("Fred","Unit x","Blah Street","1234"),
                new Customer("Mary","Unit Z","Other Lane","4321")
                );
        for(long customerId: customersAdded) {
            int limit = (new Random()).nextInt(10) + 1;
            for(int ii = 0; ii < ((new Random()).nextInt(10) + 1); ii++) {
                dao.insertOrder(new Order(customerId,5));
            }
        }

        // Get counts writing them to the log
        Log.d(TAG,"There are " + dao.getCustomerCount() + " customers in the Database");
        Log.d(TAG,"There are " + dao.getOrderCount() + " orders in the Database");
        // Get Customers with their orders writing info to the log
        for(CustomerOrders co: dao.getAllCustomersWithTheirOrders()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Customer is " + co.customer.customerName + " " + co.customer.getCustomerUnitNumber() + " etc.");
            for(Order o: co.orderList) {
                 Log.d(TAG,"Order Id is " + o.getOrderId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which could produce something like :-

```
2021-05-08 07:09:14.183 D/DBINFO: There are 2 customers in the Database
2021-05-08 07:09:14.184 D/DBINFO: There are 7 orders in the Database
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Customer is Fred Unit x etc.
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 1
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 2
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 3
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 4
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Customer is Mary Unit Z etc.
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 5
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 6
2021-05-08 07:09:14.189 D/DBINFO: Order Id is 7
```

I'd suggest that the above is all quite tidy rather than a mashup.

However, where things do start to get a little more complex would be, for example, if you wanted to get the Customer and their orders BUT only where the quantity were a specific amount or greater than or lesser than an amount.

Using :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE quantity = :x")
List<CustomerOrders> CustomerWithOrdersOfX(int x);
```

Fails to compile with :-

```
AllDao.java:41: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: quantity)
List<CustomerOrders> CustomerWithOrdersOfX(int x);
```

You could then use:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM customer JOIN `order` ON `order`.customerReference = customerId WHERE quantity = :x")
List<CustomerOrders> getCustomersWithOrdersOfX(int x);
```

However, putting this into practice could result in :-

```
D/DBINFO: Number of Customers with Orders that have a quantity of 4 is 1
D/DBINFO: Customer = Mary
D/DBINFO: OrderID is 18 Qnty = 0
D/DBINFO: OrderID is 19 Qnty = 1
D/DBINFO: OrderID is 20 Qnty = 4
D/DBINFO: OrderID is 21 Qnty = 2
D/DBINFO: OrderID is 22 Qnty = 0
```

The expectation would be that only Order ID 20 (which has the quantity of 4) is extracted as that is the only order with 4.

However, @Relation gets **ALL** children belonging to the @Embedded. To overcome this issue is where things can start to mashup.